# walker - 0 level on submenu formatting

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I need to create this structure:

```
<div class="submenu-box">
    <ul class="submenu-box__links">...</ul>
    <ul class="submenu-box__links">...</ul>
    <ul class="submenu-box__links">...</ul>
</div>
```

but I'm getting this:

```
<div class="submenu-box">
    <ul class="submenu-box__links">...</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my custom walker:

```
class MegaMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Parent menu title
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $parentMenu = null;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = [])
    {
        $image = get_field('megamenu_image', $this->parentMenu);
        $description = get_field('megamenu_description', $this->parentMenu);

        switch ($depth) {
            case 0:
                $output .= "<div class=\"submenu\">";

                if ($image !== null && $description !== null) {
                    $output .= "<div class=\"submenu-box submenu-box__intro\">";
                        $output .= "<img src=\"$image\" alt=\"Menu ".$this->parentMenu->title."\" width=\"400\" height=\"219\">";
                        $output .= "<h3>";
                            $output .= "<a href=\"#\">".$this->parentMenu->title."</a>";
                        $output .= "</h3>";
                        $output .= "<p>$description</p>";
                    $output .= "</div>";
                }

                $output .= "<div class=\"submenu-box\">";
                $output .= "<ul class=\"submenu-box__links\">";
                break;

            case 1:
            case 2:
                $output .= "<ul>";
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = [])
    {
        switch ($depth) {
            case 0:
                $output .= "</ul>";
                $output .= "</div>";
                $output .= "</div>";
                break;

            case 1:
            case 2:
                $output .= "</ul>";
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0)
    {
        if ($depth === 0) {
            $this->parentMenu = $item;
        }

        $title = $item->title;
        $permalink = $item->url;
        $css_classes = $item->classes;
        $css_classes = join(' ',
            apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class',
                array_filter($css_classes),
                $item,
                $args
            )
        );

        switch($depth) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                $output .= '<li class="'.$css_classes.'">::: ' . $depth;
                $output .= '<a href="'.$permalink.'">';
                $output .= $title;
                break;
        }

        $output .= '</a>';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [])
    {
        switch($depth) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                $output .= '</a>';
                $output .= "</li>";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?
Here is my nav structure:

```
PARENT (main menu position)
-- Child
--- SubChild
-- Child
--- SubChild
```

**wp_nav_menu**

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'walker' => new MegaMenuWalker(),
    'container' => 'div',
));
```

Comment: Where's the code that makes use of this walker and displays the menu? The call to `wp_nav_menu` and its parameters is very important! But it's missing from your question :(

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry, I have updated question with it :)

Comment: I just try the class with the call of `wp_nav_menu` and I have the complet menu with children and subchildren (but not other one below level 2). look the HTML result here : https://pastebin.com/Qr9gpzFy